# Why won't my tracked array update in Ember Octane?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-3

I'm trying out Octane, and for some reason, if I show an array in a template and I add a new object to it, the UI doesn't update. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my template:

```
<label for="new-field-name">Field Name</label>
<Input id="new-field-name" @value={{this.newFieldName}} type="text" />
<button {{on "click" this.addField}}>Add field</button>

{{#each this.fields as |field|}}
    <p>{{field.name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

And the component:

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class ConfigControlsComponent extends Component {
    @tracked fields = []
    @tracked newFieldName = ''

    @action addField() {
        this.fields.push({
            name: this.newFieldName
        })
        console.log(this.fields)
    }
}
```

The `console.log` shows the array with the new object added to it, and the `fields` array is tracked, but nothing changes when I click the button.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you use `tracked` with arrays, you need to "reset" the array so that Ember notices that there has been a change. Try doing `this.fields = this.fields` after pushing a new object into the array.

Edit: some linters will guard against self-assignment. So, instead, we could pull from *immutability* patterns, and set using a new array, as shown below.

```js
export default class ConfigControlsComponent extends Component {
  @tracked fields = []
  @tracked newFieldName = ''

  @action addField() { 
    // add this line
    this.fields = [...this.fields, {
      name: this.newFieldName
    }]; 
  }
}
```

If you are trying to use `tracked` with an object instead of an array, you have two options:

First, you could create a class where all the properties on the object are tracked:

```
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';

class Address {
  @tracked street;
  @tracked city;
}

class Person {
  address = new Address();

  get fullAddress() {
    let { street, city } = this.address;

    return `${street}, ${city}`;
  }
}
```

Or, second, you could use the same "reset" approach as the array example above.

Comment: You could do `this.fields = [...this.fields, { name: this.newFieldName }]` as well.

Comment: `pushObject` instead `push` should work fine. This notifies ember to re-render.

Comment: IMHO @Aswath's answer looks right. The OP should be using `pushObject` method since it is compatible with KVO compliant classes. Additionally, it would be desirable to use `EmberArray` class explicitly, through `A([])`

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not automatically tracked if one of their element change.
You cannot do:

```
this.fields.push({
        name: this.newFieldName
    })
```

But they get tracked if you change the whole array, using the spread operator for example:

```
this.fields = [...this.fields, {name: this.newFieldName}]
```

Or eventually you can use *EmberArray*, see https://guides.emberjs.com/release/in-depth-topics/autotracking-in-depth/#toc_arrays