# How to mutate an array's value in "each" helper in Ember JS (Octane)

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-octane

I have an array of strings passed as an argument to a component, inside the component I am using "each" helper to render each string in a text input.  I tried the following approach.

```html
MainComponent.hbs
<Component @model={{model}}/>

//Eg: model.list = ["Jack", "Sparrow"];

Component.hbs
<div>
    {{#each this.args.model.list as |name|}}
    <div>           
         <PaperInput @value={{ name }} 
            @placeholder="Enter a Name"
            @onChange={{action (mut name)}}/>        
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

I am running into the error "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Assertion Failed: You can only pass a path to mut". Would really appreciate if anyone can let me know What's going wrong here.

Answer (score 4):

The value that are derived from helpers (`each` in your case) cannot be mutated using `mut` helper as the helpers usually don't pass down or hold the values to change the original property.

For instance,

It makes sense if we are mutating a value as below where `capitalize` is a helper:

```html
<button {{action (mut name) (capitalize name)}}>
 Capitalize
</button>
```

however, below snippet does't fit right as helper returns the value one way!

```html
<button {{action (mut (capitalize name)) name}}>
 Capitalize
</button>
```

the same thing is going on with the `each` helper and the looped through value cannot be mutated! This [code comment](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/@ember/-internals/glimmer/lib/helpers/mut.ts#L130-L142) might be useful for further digging.

You can change your snippet to handle the `onChange` in the backing component class instead:

```html
<div>
    {{#each this.args.model.list as |name index|}}
    <div>           
         <PaperInput @value={{ name }} 
            @placeholder="Enter a Name"
            @onChange={{this.changeName index}}/>        
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

```js
// component.js

changeName(index, nameToBeUpdated) {
 // change the name here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gokul. how would you update the array in changeName so that it re renders?

Comment: For example,  this.args.model.list[index] = name would not work.

Comment: That's how that tracking system works in Ember octane now. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468327/why-wont-my-tracked-array-update-in-ember-octane?answertab=active#tab-top) should help. 
Also, there is [a section](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/tracked-properties/#toc_arrays) on property tracking in octane guide which explains an alternative method!

Comment: Figured it out. Posted the full implmentation :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Posting the full implementation for the benefit of others. I passed down the index value to component's action as suggested in Gokul's answer but ran into another problem. There was no straight forward method to change the array's value. So I used the Mutable Array's replace method do that. That again caused another problem, every time I entered a character in the text input it was chaning the array value and re rendering the list which took the focus out of the input. So in "each" helper I had to set key="@index" which tells the helper to rerender only if there is a array index change, not the value.

```js
Component.js

@action
 updateName( index, name ) {
    this.args.model.list.replace(index, 1, [name]);     
 }
```

```html
MainComponent.hbs

<Component @model={{model}}/>


Component.hbs

{{#each this.args.model.list key="@index" as |name index|}}
    <div>           
         <PaperInput @value={{ name }} 
            @placeholder="Enter a Name"
            @onChange={{action this.updateName index}}/>        
     </div>
{{/each}}
```